# Find the number of pairs of positive integers satisfying the inequality

Tags: c++, geometry, inequality

I'm trying to solve a programming problem where I have to display the number of positive integer solutions of the inequality `x² + y² < n`, where `n` is given by the user. I've already written a code that seems to work but not as fast as I'd like it to. Is there any way to speed it up?
My current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long n, i, r, k, p, a;
    cin >> k;
    while (k--)
    {
        r = 0;
        cin >> n;
        p = sqrt(n);
        for (i = 1; i <= p; i++)
        {
            a = sqrt(n - (i * i));
            r += a;
            if ((((i * i) + (a * a)) == n) && (a > 0))
            {
                r--;
            }
        }
        cout << r << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Edit:

This is a solution for [this task](https://www.spoj.com/KOLO/problems/NIEROWN/).

**The task in English:**
Find the number of natural solutions `(x≥1, y≥1)` of the inequality `x²+y² < n`, where `0 < n < 2147483647`. For example, for `n=10` there are 4 solutions: `(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)`.

**Input**
In the first line of input the number of test cases `k` is given. In the next `k` lines, there are the `n` values given.

**Output**
In the output, you have to display in separate lines the number of natural solutions of the inequality.

**Example**

**Input:**

```
2
10
11
```

**Output:**

```
4
6
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `k` here? what about `n`? It's always good practice to properly name your variables

Comment: Questions about code that works but you believe could be improved should be asked [at Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Note that I've linked you to the how to ask page. You owe it to yourself to read up on what they expect in a question before posting.

Comment: [Your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know why, if you only ever use `i * i`, you're bothering with `p = sqrt(n);`?

Comment: realize for a moment that sqrt returns a double which you are forcing assignment to a long long...If you plagiarized this code then you can blame it on someone other than yourself.  I fixed your code up a bit (got rid of the long long) and it runs quite quickly...what do you mean by "speeding it up"?  What does 'k' do?  How is the user of the program supposed to know how to use it?  How are people who look at the code supposed to know what the intended use is?

Comment: I've added the details you were asking about.

Comment: The reading between the lines point of the questions about `n` and `k` is they have completely useless names. They are prompts for you to improve the code to make it readable. Few people will help with code that looks like alphabet soup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems fast already. The main possibility to reduce the time spent is to suppress the call to `sqrt`in the loop. This is obtained by considering that the value `a = sqrt(n - (i * i))` does not vary very much from one iteration to the next one.

Here is the code:

```
    r = 0;
    p = sqrt(n);
    if ((p*p) == n) p--;
    a = p;
    for (long long i = 1; i <= p; i++)
    {
        while ((n-i*i) <= a*a) {
            --a;
        }
        r += a;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this speeded up the algorithm a bit.

Comment: Is it fast enough ?

Comment: Still takes a bit longer than the time limit.

Comment: Could you detail how much it was improved, and how much it is still to be improved? Are you in a hurry ? I have an idea, no time now

Comment: The time taken was reduced by about 20% and I need the code to work about twice as fast as my original solution. I'm in no hurry and there is also a little possibility that my teacher accidentally set a bit too strict time limits, because as of yet, nobody from my class has written any solution that is correct and doesn't exceed the time limits.

Comment: I guess you did not forget to set the compiler options correctly  (-O2 e.g.)

Comment: When I wrote about time the program takes to execute, I meant the time measured by an [online judge](https://szkopul.edu.pl/), which doesn't depend on what compiler options I use on my computer.

Comment: When I compare you program with mine, I got that it is twice faster (time gain 50%), at least for large values

Comment: So maybe it's because you tested it on larger data than me? Didn't your test data exceed the max values given in the task?

Comment: No, I respected  the max value. But I was rather near.

Comment: I just realised that your max value 2147483647 is equal to 2^31-1! Therefore you can use `int` (on most machines) instead of `long long` !! This could fasten the program a bit

Comment: My teacher has just changed the time limits. They were simply too strict. Now even my original solution is fast enough. But anyway, thanks for your help.